# spark-submit "Unable to connect to server"

Tags: apache-spark

I've been using spark-submit to launch applications in cluster mode, usually like this:

```
spark-submit ^
--master spark://master_ip_from_web_ui:6066 ^
--class MyClass ^
--deploy-mode cluster ^
--conf "maybesomeconf=val"
path_to_app_jar_on_worker_nodes ^
arg1 args
```

The master web ui is up and running, and shows all the workers connected to the cluster.  However, I get this response after submitting the application:

```
16/07/06 14:47:02 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://master_ip:6066.
16/07/06 14:47:03 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://master_ip:6066.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://master_ip:6066 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
```

Comment: Have you tried to ping master_ip from the driver node, i.e. where you are running spark-submit on?

Comment: I'm running spark-submit from a machine on the same LAN as the cluster.  I can ping the master server, as well as connect to the master UI on port 8080.  For now I'm running the job from a worker node inside the cluster using remote desktop on the remote machine

Comment: And from the worker node the job submission works? If so, it seems a network configuration issue. Being in the same LAN is not enough, usually clusters are "protected" in some sense and it may be that the administrator opened access to 8080 (ours didn't so I have to route via SOCKS).

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah that sounds like the issue.  Though it's odd because everything was working yesterday.

Comment: I was having this same issue, but the solution for me was hidden in your question.  I was using port 7077, but changing to 6066 made it work for me.